# Wordpress Multisite shared menu

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a site (http://abraxas.pw) using wordpress multisite. I manually create the subdomains which become separate sites. A sample subdomain is: http://tekspec.abraxas.pw

I would like to do the following:

Include a default menu/nav bar (exists currently on the primary site but needs to be rebuilt on all other sites?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution which works - there weren't any other plugins like this one. It allows you to create a network wide menu and apply it to all sites in the network

http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/networkwide-menu/

Comment: Did you find any other solution for this other than a plugin? I am wanting to do the exact same, but preferably I would like tabs as the menu network-wide.